# JSON Exception : JSONObject xxxx is not a JSONObject

Tags: java, json, exception, tags

I want to use this class

https://code.google.com/p/ext-c/source/browse/trunk/src/nz/ac/vuw/ecs/kcassell/similarity/GoogleDistanceCalculator.java

This is my code (my object is to compute pairwise Google distance between all my tags)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
   Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(new File (yyy));
   try {
      GoogleDistanceCalculator googleDistanceCalculator =
         new GoogleDistanceCalculator();
      ArrayList<String>  Alltags = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (s.hasNext()) {
         Alltags.add(s.next());
      }
      ArrayList<Double>  arraysNGD = new ArrayList<Double>();
      for (int i = 0; i < Alltags.size(); i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < Alltags.size(); j++) {
            if (j!=i)
               arraysNGD.add(
                  googleDistanceCalculator.calculateDistance(
                     Alltags.get(i).trim(), Alltags.get(j).trim()));
         }
      }
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Errors

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["responseData"] is not a JSONObject.
  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:508)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.getCountFromGoogleQuery(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:196)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.getCountFromQuery(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:173)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.numResultsFromWeb(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:150)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.calculateDistance(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:262)
  at test.Zssai.main(Zssai.java:55)
```

NB

When I try for example

```
googleDistanceCalculator.calculateDistance("forest","plant");
```

It works fine with no error

**EDIT**

```
nature  sky
  org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["responseData"] is not a JSONObject.
  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:508)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.getCountFromGoogleQuery(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:196)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.getCountFromQuery(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:173)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.numResultsFromWeb(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:150)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.calculateDistance(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:262)
  at test.Zssai.main(Zssai.java:51)

nature  blue
  org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["responseData"] is not a JSONObject.
  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:508)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.getCountFromGoogleQuery(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:196)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.getCountFromQuery(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:173)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.numResultsFromWeb(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:150)
  at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.calculateDistance(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:262)
at test.Zssai.main(Zssai.java:51)
    nature  water
    org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["responseData"] is not a JSONObject.
at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:508)
at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.getCountFromGoogleQuery(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:196)
at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.getCountFromQuery(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:173)
at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.numResultsFromWeb(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:150)
at nz.ac.vuw.ecs.kcassell.similarity.GoogleDistanceCalculator.calculateDistance(GoogleDistanceCalculator.java:262)
at test.Zssai.main(Zssai.java:51)
    nature  clouds
```

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println`s to your loop to print `Alltags.get(i).trim()` and `Alltags.get(j).trim()`. Also, your `j` loop should start at `i+1`, otherwise you're calculating twice for A->B and B->A.

Comment: @PaulGrime
Ok I added the result to my question

Comment: Thanks. Can you print both on the same line and print to `System.err` not `System.out`. So your `println`s and the exception traces don't interfere with each other. But it looks like it could be a problem with your data, and some data items not resulting in a valid JSON response from whichever service you connect to.

Comment: I reedited my question 

I think also the problem is with my data but how to solve it?

Comment: You debug the app, or add logging statements, such that you identify which data causes the error, and then don't use those data. Can you debug through the `GoogleDistanceCalculator` code and find out what data items you actually need to use instead?

Comment: but I should use those data

Comment: What does `String urlString = makeYahooQueryString(searchTerm)` equate to? If you paste that URL in a browser what do you get? What is the response from the service you call? Impossible to help without knowing these things.

Comment: this is the urlString (I change yahooQuery to GoogleQuery)


http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=nature

Comment: Can you read in the service response into a string and print that? I'm guessing this could be a content encoding (e.g. gzip, not gzip, etc) or character encoding (e.g. UTF8 or ISO8895-1, etc) issue. But maybe the JSON would fail to parse in that case.

Comment: I don't understand you:/ 
where can I found the service response

Comment: The service URL that this - https://code.google.com/p/ext-c/source/browse/trunk/src/nz/ac/vuw/ecs/kcassell/similarity/GoogleDistanceCalculator.java - talks to.

Comment: this ? "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search

Comment: `org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject` is failing to find a value in the data that comes back from Google/Yahoo, so if we can look at the response (and the code you linked to is responsible for reading this) then we can see if that's the problem.

Comment: An hour ago I have tried this,
    
       googleDistanceCalculator.calculateDistance("forest","plant");
       
It works fine 

but when I retried now I got the famous error "is not JSONObject"!

Comment: the yahoo service is premium ...

Comment: "The Google Search and Language APIs shown to the right have been officially deprecated. They will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day will be limited"

this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

yahoo boss is not free

and the Google search API is depracated 
so it allow only a limit number of query 
when I surpass this number I get the error

```
    org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["responseData"] is not a JSONObject.
```

So to solve this problem I should use other search engine API

this API may be useful

```
   http://www.sindice.com/
```